# how can i retrieve different child firebase database in single activity

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to retrieve data from Firebase Database and set them to text view. My database has different multiple child data. I want to retrieve all child in a single activity like globally. I have a different card view click in the main activity. when I click on any item it does not show the same child data with related that item. It shows single child data on every item click. How can I get them in a signal Activity on card view click? I am new to Android and I have tried multiple answers here, but failed. Can anyone help me with this?

[image: [1]: https://photos.app.goo.gl/DxYjK6jG182qUY6n9 "database"]

```
public class GlobalActivity extends AppCompatActivity

    RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    List<User> myUserList;
    User mUser;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private DatabaseReference db;
    private ValueEventListener eventListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_global);


        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait its loding..");
                mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.farazList);

        GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(AhmedFarazActivity.this, 1);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

        myUserList = new ArrayList<>();

        final ReAdapter reAdapter = new ReAdapter(GlobalActivity.this, myUserList);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(reAdapter);

        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Spinner").child("US");
        progressDialog.show();
        eventListener = db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                myUserList.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    User userData = ds.getValue(User.class);
                    myUserList.add(userData);
                }
                reAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Handle to click**

This is handler in the adapter when I click on any item it does not show the same child data with related that item. It shows single child data on every item click.

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder, int position) {

        // Hide data
        holder.nameText.setText(models.get(position).getName());
        holder.img.setImageResource(models.get(position).getImg());

        holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(View view, int pos) {
                //Go to UK Item to show UK data
                if (models.get(pos).getName().equals("US")){
                    //Start Display Activity on click
                    Toast.makeText(c, "US", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(c, GlobalActivity.class);
                    c.startActivity(intent);
                }
                //Go to UK Item to show UK data
                if (models.get(pos).getName().equals("UK")){
                    //Start System Info Activity on click
                    Toast.makeText(c, "UK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(c, GlobalActivity.class);
                    c.startActivity(intent);

                }

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What's wrong with this code? Do you have an error?

Comment: i have fix my error

Comment: Please post it as an answer so other future vistors can see it.

Comment: now posted answer you can check

Answer (score 0):

**Now i figure out my solution**

I add just Intent.putExtra("data","1"); **in every handler click**

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyHolder holder, int position) {

    // Hide data
    holder.nameText.setText(models.get(position).getName());
    holder.img.setImageResource(models.get(position).getImg());

    holder.setItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(View view, int pos) {
            //Go to UK Item to show UK data
            if (models.get(pos).getName().equals("US")){
                //Start Display Activity on click
                Toast.makeText(c, "US", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(c, GlobalActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("data","1");
                c.startActivity(intent);
            }
            //Go to UK Item to show UK data
            if (models.get(pos).getName().equals("UK")){
                //Start System Info Activity on click
                Toast.makeText(c, "UK", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(c, GlobalActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("data","2");
                c.startActivity(intent);

            }

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In GlobalActivity i create a method for data**
initialize **data();** inside onCreate

```
public class GlobalActivity extends AppCompatActivity

RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
List<User> myUserList;
User mUser;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
private DatabaseReference db;
private ValueEventListener eventListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_global);


    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait its loding..");
            mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.farazList);

    GridLayoutManager gridLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(AhmedFarazActivity.this, 1);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(gridLayoutManager);

    myUserList = new ArrayList<>();

    final ReAdapter reAdapter = new ReAdapter(GlobalActivity.this, myUserList);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(reAdapter);

    data();
    progressDialog.show();
    eventListener = db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            myUserList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                User userData = ds.getValue(User.class);
                myUserList.add(userData);
            }
            reAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
}
```

**method for getting**

```
public void data() {
    String data = getIntent().getStringExtra("data");
    if (data.equals("1")) {
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Spinner").child("India");
        db.keepSynced(true);
    } else if (data.equals("2")) {
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Spinner").child("Pak");
        db.keepSynced(true);
    } else if (data.equals("3")) {
        db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Spinner").child("UK");
        db.keepSynced(true);
    }
}
```